# set focus of textbox used in directive template

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using directive to display textbox based on data model. If data mode is in edit state then I display textbox. I want that textbox focus should be set when it is rendered. I tried however couldn't find anything. Please help. Following is an example for review.

```
var myModule = angular.module('myModule', []);
myModule.directive('textbox', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div ng-if="data.mode==edit"> <input type="text" ng-model="data.value"/> </div>',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) 
    {
      scope.data =  {"mode":"edit","value":"This is text box"};
    }
  };
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dilipkumar2k6/hXYeH/1/)

Comment: my bad in bad typing of jsfiddle URL...i always do mistake to add URL in post...following is same URL http://jsfiddle.net/dilipkumar2k6/hXYeH/1/

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick.

```
scope.$watch('data.mode', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  if (newValue == 'edit') {
    element.find('input')[0].focus();
  }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hXYeH/3/)